# Sending ASCII Command using PySerial

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, hardware, pyserial

I am trying to send the followings  ASCII command:
close1

using PySerial, below is my attempt:

```
import serial

#Using  pyserial Library to establish connection
#Global Variables
ser = 0

#Initialize Serial Port
def serial_connection():
    COMPORT = 3
    global ser
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.baudrate = 38400 
    ser.port = COMPORT - 1 #counter for port name starts at 0




    #check to see if port is open or closed
    if (ser.isOpen() == False):
        print ('The Port %d is Open '%COMPORT + ser.portstr)
          #timeout in seconds
        ser.timeout = 10
        ser.open()

    else:
        print ('The Port %d is closed' %COMPORT)


#call the serial_connection() function
serial_connection()
ser.write('open1\r\n')
```

but as a result I am receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      , line 31, in <module>
        ser.write('open1\r\n')
      , line 283, in write
        data = to_bytes(data)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 76, in to_bytes
        b.append(item)  # this one handles int and str for our emulation and ints for Python 3.x
    TypeError: an integer is required
```

Not sure how I would be able to resolve that. close1 is just an example of an ASCII command I want to send there is also status1 to see if my locks are open or close, etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue arises because Python 3 stores its strings internally as unicode but Python 2.x does not. PySerial is expecting to get a `bytes` or `bytearray` as a parameter to `write`. In Python 2.x the string type would be fine for this but in Python 3.x the string type is Unicode and hence not compatible with what pySerial `write` needs.

In order to use pySerial with Python 3 you need to use a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typebytearray). So your code would look need to look like this instead:

```
ser.write(b'open1\r\n')
```

Comment: thank you that worked well. one additional question if you don't mind 1) how would i be able to print out the result of what is received such as if i type status1 it should return close1/open1 and the other question which is a bit more simple is     if (ser.isOpen() == False):
does not exactly check to see if the port is open as even when nothing is connected it bypasses that line and tryies to send a command which obviously returns an error thanks

Comment: @Jon220, I suggest you have a go at this and ask in a new question if you get stuck.